# How to break setinterval in io sockets - Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, io-socket

There is an api which sends some json data.The nodejs server get this json data and send client with websocket every 5 seconds.If the connection is on when a clent connects it works but when the client disconnects ,it doesnt stop.

The code

```
io.on('connection', function(client) {  
        var loop=setInterval(()=>{
            console.log('Client connected...');

            fetch('https://www.foo.com/api/v2/searchAssets')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(json => 
            {client.emit('news'{json});console.log(json)}),5000);

        })});

io.on('disconnetion',function(){
                clearInterval(loop);
                console.log("disconnected");
            })
```

OR

Do you have any other advice to send this json data to client side except websocket?

Thansk in advance for your supporting

Comment: Side note: Your `fetch` call is missing a check for success. You're not the only one, this is such a common error I [wrote it up on my anemic little blog](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is a scope problem. When you declare the `loop` var, it's local to the callback of the `on connection` event and doesn't exist in the `on disconnect` event. Based on the doc of how to [handle disconnection](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#Event-%E2%80%98disconnect%E2%80%99) you can move the disconnection handler inside the connection handler like this:

```
io.on('connection', function(client) {
  // Start the interval
  var loop = setInterval(()=>{
    console.log('Client connected...');

    fetch('https://www.foo.com/api/v2/searchAssets')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => {
        client.emit('news'{json});console.log(json)
      } ,5000);
  });

  // Handles disconnection inside the on connection event
  // Note this is using `client.on`, not `io.on`, and that
  // your original code was missing the "c" in "disconnect"
  client.on('disconnect', () => {
    clearInterval(loop);
    console.log("disconnected");
  });
});
```

But I would not recommend this architecture as the streamed data is independent of a client. The data can be fetched once and streamed to all. Here is how you can do it:

```
var loop

// The function startStreaming starts streaming data to all the users
function startStreaming() {
  loop = setInterval(() => {
    fetch('https://www.foo.com/api/v2/searchAssets')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => {
        // The emit function of io is used to broadcast a message to
        // all the connected users
        io.emit('news', {json});
        console.log(json);
      } ,5000);
  });
}

// The function stopStreaming stops streaming data to all the users
function stopStreaming() {
  clearInterval(loop);
}

io.on('connection',function() {
  console.log("Client connected");

  // On connection we check if this is the first client to connect
  // If it is, the interval is started
  if (io.sockets.clients().length === 1) {
    startStreaming();
  }
});

io.on('disconnetion',function() {
  console.log("disconnected");

  // On disconnection we check the number of connected users
  // If there is none, the interval is stopped
  if (io.sockets.clients().length === 0) {
    stopStreaming();
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.Does your code block set a interval belong to each user? Thanks in advance

Comment: @digging Yes it's done in this code section `// Start the interval
  intervals[client.id] = ...`. The `client.id` is used to set an interval for each client

Comment: @digging - Are you using [the API](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#Event-%E2%80%98disconnect%E2%80%99) Baboo_ links to above?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it cant be moved inside because it will be local to the callback. It can be turned into a map though

Comment: I checked and tried both of your codes blocks.Both of them works and the block code above works fine.Thanks